# Which is better? Single-page vs multi-page simple Sinatra service

Tags: ruby, rest, view, sinatra

I'm developing a small data-crunching / visualization app in Sinatra, and am split between two options.

The functionality is that you:

1. Upload a file to the app.
2. See a nice visualization of its contents.
3. Maybe start over with a new file.

So my choices are:

1. Letting both views (upload and results) be managed by the same template, thus creating a single-page app.
2. Splitting uploads and the visualization between two pages. You upload a file to '/', then are redirected to that file's URL which displays the results.

Which one is better? The advantage of the first is that I can manage it all within the same page, by passing some local vars between the two views.

On the other hand, the second seems like the more RESTful option - because each uploaded file gets its own URL and can be treated as a resource (more fine-grained control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to provide a RESTful API as well along with the web application, it is good idea to have tow different `routes`.

If you are planning to have just a web UI, it depends on how much control you want to give to the end-user.

Nothing is wrong with either of the approach. It depends on how much ease you can provide.

Comment: I don't plan implementing all the CRUD actions on the uploaded files. You create files (by uploading them); then they are deleted by a background job after some time. So it's basically only Create (POST) and Get (GET). So I guess what I have in mind is a REST API with a subset of CRUD.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about CRUD. It is always good to have clear routes IF you are planning to provide an API